sqlite3 PDOError could not find driver
I am on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC x64 using USBWebserver v10 from here as my local testserver. It uses PHP 8.1.7.
I checked if I have the requested files in php/ext folder and I really do have them. They are also correctly uncommented in the php.ini file (like: extension=php_sqlite3.dll), yet it still reports this problem below:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found), Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_php_curl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlite3.dll' (tried: Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found), Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_php_sqlite3.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlite.dll' (tried: Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found), Z:/_SERVER_\\php\\ext\\php_php_pdo_sqlite.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

I see it for some reason look for a path with '\\' instead of single '/' - could that be the reason? If so, how to solve that?

This is not the official site. The official site is usbwebserver.net
The author stopped updating several years ago.
Some sites decided to update the server on their own, and they did it very badly.
This is the worst update I've ever seen.
usbwebserver was designed under 32-bit architecture, which also runs on 64-bit.
This site from which you downloaded usbwebserver, made an incorrect mix between 32 and 64 bit files, which leads to an update with many errors, among others a very poorly configured database, leaving a very bad reputation for the author of this excellent server.
It doesn't run on Windows 7 32 and 64 bits. When it really should.
In Windows 8.1 32 bits Apache does not run, only MySQL but with many errors. When it really should.
On Windows 10 64 bits Apache and MySQL run but with many errors. Because of the terrible update they made.
Only one Spanish site made the correct update of usbwebserver, which runs from Windows 7 and higher versions in either 32 or 64 bit architecture.
SOLUTION:
Download the correct update at usbwebserver.uk. Any questions or problems will be resolved there.
